# What is stopping attacks on the link in the action attribute in HTML forms?

Tags: security, websecurity

I know the title sounds confusing, so here is what I'm wondering:

Let's say I have a page where users can sign in, at `https://example.com/login`. The form in the page looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://example.com/api/auth/login">
    <!-- input fields here -->
    <button type="submit" value="Sign in">
</form>
```

The script at `https://example.com/api/auth/login` checks if the user specified username and password is correct. It then responds with JSON appropriately.

However, one can just grab this link in the `action` attribute and guess usernames and passwords by performing repeated requests. What should I, as a developer, do to prevent such attacks from happening?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the attack you described is cross-site request forgery, CSRF.

You should indeed implement csrf protection, you can choose from several options. Synchronizer tokens can be used if your application is stateful (a random token stored in the session and generated in the page html, then sent and compared on the server upon each post request), or something like double posting (setting the same token in a cookie and as a request header and comparing the two on the server) if your app is stateless.

It doesn't only affect logins, but any action that implies a state change in your application (which is mostly but not exclusively data change).

Also note that due to the same origin policy, any attacker trying to exploit this will not directly know whether the login (or any other action) succeeded. But many times it doesn't really matter much, they can just guess.